# Tunnel / Forward connections on server 1 to server 2

Tags: debian, proxy, linux-networking, port-forwarding, tunnel

I have now spent some time researching, but I haven't found a working solution to the following problem:

I want to tunnel any requests on server 1, port x to server 2, port x.
The port stays the same, I just want to tunnel any data being sent to server 1 on port x to server 2.

The connection would look like this:

Client > Server 1 >tunnel> Server 2

and reverse:

Server 2 >tunnel> Server1 > Client

Is that possible?
If yes, how?
The servers are both running Debian 8.

Please excuse me if this is a total noob question, but I am just getting started with servers and stuff.

Thanks ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is called Proxy(ing). Yes this is possible by enabling the forwarding module on server1 and then add the appropriate forwarding rules on your iptables.

For example:

*On server1:
**Enable Forwading:**

```
echo "1" > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward  
sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
```

**Add forwarding Rules on Iptables**

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING --dst server1_ip -p tcp --dport portX -j DNAT --to-destination server2_ip:portX
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -p tcp --dst server2_ip --dport portX -j SNAT --to-source server1_ip
iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT --dst server1_ip -p tcp --dport portX -j DNAT --to-destination server2_ip:portX
```

where:
 **portX:** The port you wish to forward
 **server1_ip:** Server ip which receives initial ip and forwards to server2.
 **server2_ip:** The ip address of the server you wish to forward the traffic to.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Proxying describes it pretty well. Basically, all traffic being sent to server 1 should be tunneled to server 2 where it is being processed. The response uses the same connection and the same route(so server 1 is only there for passing stuff between the client and server 2, in both directions). Since it is no HTTP traffic, e.g. the apache proxy-mod will not work in this case.

Comment: @rocket_doge_ I have updated my answer. Give it a try and see if it works.